# Mapnik pgraster in PostGIS using ST_MapAlgebra on Tiled rasters

Tags: postgis, mapnik

Is it possible and feasible to run a simple ST_MapAlgebra on the fly for a multi-band tiled (100x100) raster with mapnik extension pgraster?

For example I am trying with this xml:

```
<Layer name="raster-layer" status="on" srs="+proj=utm +zone=56 +south +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs">
<StyleName>raster-style</StyleName>
<Datasource>
    <Parameter name="host">localhost</Parameter>
    <Parameter name="dbname">data</Parameter>
    <Parameter name="user">gisuser</Parameter>
    <Parameter name="password">pass</Parameter>
    <Parameter name="table">(select ST_MapAlgebra(rast, 1, rast, 2, '([rast1.val]+0.00000001)/([rast2.val]+0.00000001)') as rast from maps.my_raster as r where rast is not null) as foo</Parameter>
    <Parameter name="type">pgraster</Parameter>
    <Parameter name="raster_table">maps.my_raster</Parameter>
    <Parameter name="raster_field">rast</Parameter>
</Datasource>
</Layer>
</Map>
```

When I request a tile, the request takes several minutes or times out so I am guessing my request is looking at too much data. I was hoping I could get the request to run the map algebra on just the 100x100 pixels row before passing it on to pgraster.

I have looked at [OptimizeRenderingWithPostGIS](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/OptimizeRenderingWithPostGIS) which helps but is directed more that the vector data types and I think the tile rasters adds another layer of complexity.

If I run the below query in psql it takes about 1 second for 1 100x100 tile.

```
select rid,ST_MapAlgebra(rast, 1, rast, 2, '([rast1.val]+0.00000001)/([rast2.val]+0.00000001)') as rast from maps.my_raster as r limit 1
```